# dictionary[@"myKey"] VS [dictionary valueForKey:@"myKey"]

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, nsdictionary

Im just wondering whats the difference between the two, which one is faster and their pros and cons.

Comment: Do you really wish to compare `dictionary[@"myKey"]` with `[dictionary objectForKey:@"myKey"]`?

Comment: They compile to pretty much the same, look here: http://nshipster.com/object-subscripting/

Comment: @Dario The OP is asking about `valueForKey:`, not `objectForKey:`.

Comment: @rmaddy true, although I feel like the OP confused the two...

Answer (score 2):

The syntax `dictionary[@"myKey"]` is the same as calling `[dictionary objectForKeyedSubscript:@"myKey"]` which is basically the same as calling `[dictionary objectForKey:@"myKey"]`.

The method `valueForKey:` is used for KVC (Key-value coding). If the key doesn't start with `@` then it will end up giving the same result at `objectForKey:` but if the key starts with `@`, the result will be quite different.

Answer (score 1):

```
dictionary[@"myKey"]
```

is translated to

```
[dictionary objectForKeyedSubscript:key]
```

by compiler which is equivalent to

```
[dictionary objectForKey:key]
```

and

```
dictionary[@"myKey"] = value
```

is translated to

```
[dictionary setObject:newValue forKeyedSubscript:key]
```

which is equivalent to

```
[dictionary setObject:newValue forKeye:key]
```

[doc from clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#dictionary-style-subscripting)

Answer (score 0):

-valueForKey is a method that can be called on any object to get the value of a property named the given "key". It will not give the value in the dictionary for the object at the given dictionary key.

If however, you meant to ask about `-objectForKey` then `dictionary[@"myKey"]` is just a shorthand for `[dictionary objectForKey:@“myKey”]`. They both compile into the same thing.

Comment: Close but not quite. It's similar to `objectForKeyedSubscript:`, not `objectForKey:`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you should not compare

```
dictionary[@"key"]
```

with `[dictionary valueForKey: @"key"]`

The second valueForKey method uses key-value coding (KVC) which is very different.

`dictionary[@"key"]` is functionally equivalent to `[dictionary objectForKey: @"key"]` The results are the same, even though `dictionary[@"key"]` calls a slightly different method.

The first `dictionary[@"key"]`form uses new "object literal" syntax which is a recent addition to the Objective-C language.